# how to remove new div with the same name, but at a different time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that appears when you click a button and is deleted after 4 seconds.
The problem is that when it appears several times, it is immediately removed after the first 4 seconds
So when I click the button, the div is displayed and after 4 seconds it is removed, but when I click the button again after 3 seconds, another div will appear that will be deleted in 1 second.
I want to have 4 seconds for each div, don't you know how to do it?

**HTML**

```
<button onclick='div()'>Add div</button>
<div class='content'></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function div(){
 $('.content').append('<div class="newDiv">text...</div>');

 setTimeout(function(){
   $('.newDiv').remove();
 }, 4000); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the div you're adding and then just remove that one:

```
function addDiv(){
    var div = $('<div class="newDiv">text...</div>');
    $('.content').append(div);

    setTimeout(function(){
        div.remove();
    }, 4000); 
}
```

(I changed the name of the function, since function names should be verbs and I used `div` within the function to refer to the `div`.)

Side note: I'd recommend not using `onXyz`-attribute-style event handlers, not least because it means your event handler functions have to be globals, and the global namespace is **really** crowded. Instead, select the button and use `on`:

```
$("selector-for-the-button").on("click", addDiv);
```

Live Example:

```js
// Scoping function to avoid creating globals
(function() {
    var counter = 0; // Just for demonstration purposes, so we can tell them apart
    function addDiv(){
        var div = $('<div class="newDiv">div #' + counter + '...</div>');
        ++counter;
        $('.content').append(div);

        setTimeout(function(){
            div.remove();
        }, 1200); // Shortened time for demo
    }
    $(".add-div").on("click", addDiv);
})();
```

```html
<button class="add-div">Add div</button>
<div class='content'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create individual `id` instead of `class` .Because class name select the all same name of class element

```js
var inc = 0;

function div() {
  var id = "newDiv_" + inc;
  $('.content').append('<div id="' + id + '">text' + inc + '...</div>');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#' + id).remove();
  }, 4000);
  inc++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='div()'>Add div</button>
<div class='content'></div>
```

Comment: There's no need for `id`s for this.

Comment: ya..right @T.J.Crowder. i just posted different approach.This is not wrong but its also one of the method